# Kiln integration with JIRA

Tags: jira, kiln

We are happy with JIRA and there is no willingness to move away from it.  At present we have JIRA integrated well with Perforce.   However we are considering moving to Kiln.

Losing the integration with JIRA would be a blocker.

Comment: You should try the JIRA Forums, very active people there and right at the source of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perforce not Proforce, right? Kiln has an [API](http://www.fogcreek.com/Kiln/learnmore.html?section=TrackReviewsWithFogBugz#hist_ReadWriteAPI) that could be used to integrate with JIRA, but I would also consider using [Fisheye](https://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/overview) (from Atlassian) to interact directly with the Mercurial repositories used by Kiln. You could also use the JIRA Mercurial plugin that I wrote to interact with those repositories if you didn't want Fisheye for some reason.

This is an area that I know Atlassian are interested in finding out what people want. If you want to drop me a note about this I can forward it to their Dev Tools group.

Answer (score 1):

Since Kiln uses Mercurial under the hood, you might also want to consider Atlassian's [BitBucket](http://www.atlassian.com/hosted/bitbucket/), which is a hosted Mercurial repository.